# How to print (on paper)

Tags: printing, adobe-brackets

I started using Adobe Brackets last week. Specifically Brackets Sprint 26. Does anyone know how to print code from Brackets?

Why would you need this:

1. If you are limited on display space
2. If you prefer to write on your code and draw diagrams [me]

I know that you can screen capture and then print, but that's a pain. Does anyone know any other ways to print? Seems weird that it wasn't build into the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets doesn't have any built-in printing command yet – you'll need to copy/paste into some other app to print code.

You can do this with *full color* syntax highlighting using my ['Copy as HTML' extension for Brackets](https://github.com/peterflynn/copy-as-html). This lets you copy fully colored code and paste it into something like Word for printing (or save it in an HTML file and print using your browser, for that matter).

If you'd like to see a more robust printing feature built into Brackets, please vote for the [Print source code](https://trello.com/card/print-source-code/4f90a6d98f77505d7940ce88/934) feature on the Brackets backlog.